# Receiving Response 401 Unauthorised in SoapUI

Tags: api, soapui

I'm trying to test my API using SoapUI 5.4.0. I added my website SSL certificate in Keystore and my clients SSL in Truststore. I added apikey in header and parameters in parameters section. But, still I'm getting:

> response error 401 Unauthorized

Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you sent the request with configured Keystore?

example:
below Screen I have configured the ssl keystore, hope you have also done the same.
[image]

And then while sending request , you need to point the ssl keystore. For every request which requires ssl you need to do this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply after uploading private key in keystore it shows "An error occurred [Can't build keystore: [Certificate chain missing]], see error log for details"

Comment: If your server/client certificate is using a chain of certificates, then all the chain of certificates must be imported to your key store